# Repeat an experiment in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I have code which runs an experiment:

```
X=rbinom(5,1,0.5)
A=0
for (i in 1:5)
 {A=A+X[i]}
B=rbinom(A,1,0.5)
Y=0
for (i in 1:A)
 {Y=Y+B[i]}
```

I am trying to repeat the result 1000 times and store it in a vector, but am unsure how to go about it.

Comment: You're looking for `replicate`.

Comment: Also your code fails if `A = 0` when running `for(i in 1:A)...` during the final section. I ran it 3 times and it never got past 100 iterations before producing this error. Maybe you want to use an if statement to return `Y = 0` in these instances

Answer (score 1):

Taking Matthew's suggestion (a good thing to do in general), and simplifying your code:

```
res <- replicate(
  1000,
  sum(rbinom(sum(rbinom(5,1,0.5)),1,0.5))
)
```

I ran it once and got this:

```
table(res)
# res
#   0   1   2   3   4 
# 254 386 240 102  18
```

Which seems reasonable though you may want to make sure it is what you want.  The failures are happening because `A` in your code is often 0, but reformulated this way it isn't an issue (however, it means I can't easily compare your code vs. mine to make sure it is doing exactly the same thing).

Note you are very unlikely to get `5` as an outcome (in fact we don't here), because it means you have to win 5 coin flips in a row twice to show up in the final result.